# StdClass object response as variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have this response from an API request.

```
object(stdClass)#28 (3) { 
   ["Success"]=> bool(true) 
   ["Message"]=> string(0) "" 
   ["Invoice"]=> object(stdClass)#29 (4) { 
       ["Number"]=> string(6) "2313123" 
       ["Series"]=> string(2) "SM" 
       ["Link"]=> string(22) "https://randomlinkhere" 
       ["LinkPlata"]=> NULL 
   } 
}
```

To get this response i use :

```
$context  = stream_context_create($request);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

var_dump(json_decode($result));
```

Now i'm trying to read the response.
I need to read

`["Link"]=> string(133) "https://randomlinkhere"`

I need to get only that Link to a variable, like $variable = https://randomlinkhere

```
["Series"]=> string(2) "SM"
```

I need to get only that Series to a variable, like $variable = SM

I tried alot of things, nothing work.

My best result was with this :

```
$myArray = explode(',', $result);
print_r($myArray[4]);
```

Wich is giving me the next result :

```
"Link":"https://randomlinkhere"
```

Comment: `json_decode($result)->Invoice->Link`

Comment: @MartinZeitler You skipped `->Invoice`

Comment: @Barmar Nicely formatted, that might have been easier to spot.

Comment: @MartinZeitler not working

Comment: @Barmar also your code not working, no result printed.

Comment: @Vlad.G See my comment

Comment: @Vlad.G It works: https://ideone.com/978mLQ

Comment: still cant get this to work.....:(

Comment: @Barmar thx mate, is working now.